# ORDER BY on INT column inside CASE expression not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a table that looks like

```
some_table (
    item_id varchar(10) null,
    item_title varchar(200) null,
    item_url varchar(200) null,
    item_status char default '0' null,
    access_count int null,
    created_by varchar(100) default 'system' not null,
    created_date timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
)
```

When I try to execute the following SQL, the result order turns out to be incorrect, for example, 91 comes after 912.

```
SET @orderCol = 'accessCount';
SELECT
    t.item_status,
    t.item_id,
    t.item_title,
    t.item_url,
    t.access_count
FROM some_table t
WHERE DATE(t.created_date) = DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN (@orderCol = 'itemStatus') THEN t.item_status
    WHEN (@orderCol = 'itemId') THEN t.item_id
    WHEN (@orderCol = 'itemTitle') THEN t.item_title
    WHEN (@orderCol = 'itemUrl') THEN t.item_url
    WHEN (@orderCol = 'accessCount') THEN t.access_count 
END DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: A case expression returns a defined data type, always the same. (No matter which condition is true.)

Comment: Your Case statement will end up with different datatypes for different rows. Presumably SQL will then sort them all as VARCHARs? Perhaps you hsould move the case statement into the column definitions, and do some type casting there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing data types inside the [`CASE` expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) and it says here that:

> The return type of a CASE expression result is the aggregated type of
>   all result values.

In your example the return type would be `VARCHAR(200)`; the largest data type capable of storing all possible values. This explains why your numbers are sorted as strings. A better solution is to sort the columns separately but combine if they are compatible:

```
ORDER BY
    -- string columns
    CASE
        WHEN (@orderCol = 'itemStatus') THEN t.item_status
        WHEN (@orderCol = 'itemId') THEN t.item_id 
        WHEN (@orderCol = 'itemTitle') THEN t.item_title 
        WHEN (@orderCol = 'itemUrl') THEN t.item_url 
    END,
    -- numeric columns
    CASE
        WHEN (@orderCol = 'accessCount') THEN t.access_count
    END
```

The faux column containing all-NULL values will not affect the sorting.